# How can I have a temporary variable in a constexpr function?

Tags: c++, constexpr

This is a simplified version what I would like to do.

```
constexpr float f(float a, float b){
    constexpr float temp = a+b;
    return temp*temp*temp;
}
```

In my version, a+b is something much more complicated, so I don't want to cut and paste it three times. Using 3*(a+b) is also not a working solution for the real function. I'm trying to keep the question related to syntax, and not algebra. I can get it to work by moving a+b to it's own constexpr function, but I'd prefer to not pollute the namespace with otherwise useless functions.

Comment: This is the #1 suckiest thing about constexpr.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not permitted in C++11, but is now permitted in C++14.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B14#Relaxed_constexpr_restrictions

Comment: You should do it the other way around. `f2(float temp) { return temp * temp * temp; }` and `f(float a, float b) { return f2(a + b); }`. That way you avoid the 3 calls.

Comment: This doesn't matter with constexpr because it indicates to the compiler that the results of the function can be memorized and/or evaluated at compile time. The compiler will call temp once and reuse the value 3 times. Grand total of 1 add, 3 multiplies your way and my way. But, as I said in the intro, I simplified the problem because the question isn't about algebra.

Comment: @JohnK: It doesn't matter for the compiled code, but it *does* matter for the humans writing and reading that code. For the one writing it: Less repetition = less opportunity to make an error. For the one reading it: It is easier to figure out that you've got three times the same value.

Answer (score 6):

As you've discovered, you can't declare variables, even constexpr ones, inside the body of a constexpr function.

It's still possible to factor out a common expression, by passing it in as an argument to a second constexpr function.  For the example you've given here:

```
constexpr float pow3(float c) {
    return c*c*c;
}

constexpr float f(float a, float b) {
    return pow3(a+b);
}
```