# constexpr - why just a return statement?

Tags: c++, c++11

A constexpr function must just consist of a return statement and every argument should be known at compile time:

```
// constexpr functions use recursion rather than iteration
constexpr int factorial(int n)
{
    return n <= 1 ? 1 : (n * factorial(n-1));
}
```

Why just the return statement? I mean, why this is wrong?

```
// constexpr functions use recursion rather than iteration
constexpr int factorial(int n)
{
    int a = 222; //another variable
    return n <= 1 ? 1 : (n * factorial(n-1));
}
```

Comment: I suspect it is just a means to keep it simple for compiler implementations.

Comment: Because the Standard says so. Allowing for more general functions would complicate the life of compiler writers quite a lot (anyway, C++14 does lift some of those restrictions)

Comment: Because allowing variables would mean adding a lot of other (more complicated) restrictions. So they kept it simple for their introduction. There are ways around it anyway (calling a `constexpr` function from another one, for example)

Comment: (which in fact is what that factorial function is doing; if it wasn't `constexpr` it could have been written as a variable and a loop, even though it's usually used as an example of recursion for some reason)

Comment: This is not a practical question. The practical version is answered here: [How can I have a temporary variable in a constexpr function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11917582/how-can-i-have-a-temporary-variable-in-a-constexpr-function)

Comment: "every argument should be known at compile time" Huh? What do you mean? It's perfectly legal to call a `constexpr` function with arguments only known at runtime.

Comment: @DyP but then you don't have a `constexpr` result.

Comment: Not that this add anything practical to the discussion, but to be strict: apart from return statements C++11 allows other statements: typedef/alias declarations,using declarations, static_asserts and empty statements in constexpr function bodies.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It simplifies the implementation, as Andy Prowl says. That possibly answers "Why", but it doesn't say how it does that.

A function with only a return value, and more specifically one without local variables, is a special situation for a compiler.  This function is now comprised of a single expression: the function's AST needs only to have a single root. That lack of variables means this expression can be evaluated without a full-blown virtual machine to process it, rather a simple tree expression evaluator can be used. For various reasons the compiler probably already has such an evaluator, or could create one relatively easily (it becomes a tree simplification pass).

Knowing that only `constexpr` is used inside the expression also provides a key simplification. This guarantees that each vertex in the function AST has the same properties, even if it is a function call. The entire `constexpr` mechanism is then a generalized form of const-folding. And though it isn't always done at this high level in the compiler, it ensures it can be implemented without a huge effort (compared to a full VM).

Back to the "why" question. The restriction is driven primarily by resource limitations on the vendors. This feature, as specified, is not a huge effort and thus the vendors can actually implement it in a reasonable period of time. If there were no such restrictions, in particular allowing local variables, it greatly increases the amount of work needed. From the user's perspective (us, the programmers), the restrictions are however entirely arbitrary.

Comment: Nice answer. `constexpr` actually asks the compiler to **interpret** it (rather than compile), so striving for simplicity is understandable. A nice addition, though, would be `static if` (useful for `constexpr`, not just for templates), about which status I am not sure now.

Comment: I guess it's also for another reason. You cannot have infinite loops, and inifite recursive calls can be detected simply by forcin a recursion limit. Also any change to constexpr allowing more things would also implies more complex invariants that users have to respect in order to get code compile without wandering why it is not compiling. Also I have doubt that actually you also need to "prove" that constexpr works, and prooving it for arbitrary code would be hard or impossible also from theorical point of view.

Answer (score 13):

**Why:**

Because `constexpr` is a fairly new and radical concept in C++11 and it is difficult to transition a major language standard to something completely new.  Conservatism rules.

For C++1y (currently targeted at C++14), your example is legal.  Tip of trunk clang already implements it under the `-std=c++1y` flag.